# Как поменять регистр символа без ::tolower? C++

Tags: c++, строки, std

Простая задача - сменить регистр символа на нижний. Однако эта простая задача обернулась проблемой от такого кода:

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Вроде все должно работать, но фишка в том, что ::tolower возвращает не char, а int. Из-за этого кода мой компилятор прерывает сборку, считая последующее сужающее преобразование из int в char - ошибкой с потерей данных. Отключить флаг, чтобы компилятор выдавал на это варнинг, а не ошибку, я не могу по определенным причинам.

Есть ли способ обойти эту ошибку или уменьшить регистр буквы без ::tolower? Побочный вопрос из любознательности: Почему вообще tolower принимает и возвращает int, а не char?

Comment: Используйте библиотеку ICU.

Comment: @user7860670 можно ли это быстро сделать средствами стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: Нельзя. *"эта простая задача"* - вы явно недооцениваете сложность этой задачи. Если речь не идет о регистре ASCII символов, то это дело весьма нетривиальное.

Comment: Вообще, для ascii (даже если в строке `str` есть русские буквы в utf-8 (естественно, они не будут преобразовываться)) решение задачи ***сменить регистр символа на нижний*** элементарно -- `for (char *s = str; *s; s++)  if ('A' <= *s && *s <= 'Z') *s |= 0x20;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так?

```
[](char ch) { return (char)::tolower((unsigned char)ch); }
```

Comment: От того, что мы запихнем ::tolower в лямбду сужающее преобразование никуда не денется) Все равно ругается, увы

Comment: @ComeInRage, ругается на явный каст как на сужающее преобразование? Да не может такого быть.

Comment: Может там жёсткий статический анализатор прикручен и хочет static_cast?

Comment: Добавил каст аргумента в `unsigned char`. Иначе - неопределенное поведение на отрицательных символах...

Comment: @KoVadim, хотеть он может, но неужели он неспособен выдать другое сообщение об ошибке и показывает для нежелательного каста и отсутствия каста одно и то же?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а разве он нужен?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, прочитал. Действительно нужен о_О

Comment: Вот если бы автор вопроса показал точное сообщение об ошибке, тогда можно было бы сказать точно. А так это все просто попытка потереть хрустальный шар

Comment: @Qwertiy это очень странно, но даже ругалось на явный каст. Причем ругалось на код внутри `transform`. Помог явный static_cast к `unsigned char` и использование std::tolower внутри лямбды. К тому же изначально в вашем ответе не было явного каста. Но все равно спасибо за мысль

Comment: @ComeInRage, из int'f в char был всегда.

Answer (score 3):

Если почитать документацию, то там написано, что tolower не рекомендуется использовать с стандартными алгоритмами [напрямую](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower). Там же приведен пример использования.
Вот такая штука. Но почему функция принимает int. Потому что си функция делает так же и для сохранения совместимости, так оставили. Но почему си функция такая? Вот тут все сложнее. В множестве char не выделили место под символ EOF, который обозначает конец ввода/файла. И кому то пришла в голову идея использовать для этого отдельное значение. Сейчас бы использовали наверно std::optional, а тогда просто использовали int. Тот же getchar возвращает int. И много других функций рядом так делают и проблем с типами нет.

Вот так старый костыль вылазит боком даже сейчас. Парная тема на английском https://stackoverflow.com/q/17452847/644688

На английском сайте есть пара примеров ручками написанных функций https://stackoverflow.com/a/313990/644688 - возможно, там есть для Вас решение.

Answer (score 0):

Уж если очень хочется и нужно исключительно для `ASCII`:

```
char
ctl(char c) { /* char to lower */
    return c > '@' && c < '[' ? c + ' ' : c;
}

char
ctu(char c) { /* char to upper */
    return c > '`' && c < '{' ? c - ' ' : c;
}
```

```
::std::string test { "Some string only WITH ASCII symBols ;)" };
::std::cout << test << '\n';
::std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), ctl);
::std::cout << test << '\n';
::std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), ctu);
::std::cout << test << '\n';
```

https://ideone.com/voufHG

[image: ASCII Table]

Comment: `c > '@' && c < '['` Забавно, но `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'` понятнее. :) Аналогично сложение: `c + ('a' - 'A')`, и т.п.

Comment: Где меньше, вроде столько же? Таблица-то да, но соседние символы надо вспоминать или смотреть в таблице, а A,Z - нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, операций столько же, а вот количество нажатий на клавиши сокращается (энергосбереженое, однако ... -))

Comment: Ну да ладно, я думал что компилятор все же сделает 2 операции, но нет =) он делает оптимизацию и превращает 2й вариант в первый =)

Comment: если бы было енергозбережение, то вместо странного + ' ' было бы написано + 32. Это же на символ короче! (более того, шифт нажимать не нужно).